# files upload using express 4.15 not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using express for the first time, and got some problem while uploading files. I've followed many tutorials but no one worked. I just got an empty page and no file is uploaded

### index1.jade

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
head
    title
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
body
    form(role="form", action="/", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
    div(class="form-group")
        label(for="onixfile") Upload ONIX File        
        input(type="file", name="onixfile", id="onixfile")
        input(type="submit")
```

### app.js

```
 var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var index = require('./routes/index');
    var users = require('./routes/users');
    var multer = require('multer');

    var app = express();
    var multer = require('multer');
    var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });
    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.use('/', index);
    app.use('/users', users);

    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    });

    // error handler
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      // set locals, only providing error in development
      res.locals.message = err.message;
      res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

      // render the error page
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error');
    });

    module.exports = app;
```

### route/index.js

```
    var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var router = express.Router();
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index1', { title: 'ONIX Validator' });
});

router.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function(req, res){
    var file = '/' + req.file.filename;
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.open("./uploads",'r',function(err, fd){
    fs.readFile(file ,function(err, data){
      if(err) throw err;
      fs.writeFile("./uploads/"+req.file.filename, data), function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }else {
            console.log("Done");
        }
      }
     });
    });


});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You're creating a `multer` instance but not doing anything with it. See [the fine manual](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage) on how to use it.

Comment: You have to use the mullter as a middleware on the route that you want to upload files to.

Comment: could you please, give me an examlpe  @robertklep

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your route/index.js

```
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

router.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function(req, res){

    var file = '/' + req.file.filename;
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.open("./uploads",'r',function(err, fd){
    fs.readFile(file ,function(err, data){
      if(err) throw err;
      fs.writeFile("./uploads/"+req.file.filename, data), function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }else {
            console.log("Done");
        }
      }
     });
    });


});
```

This should upload the file to your applications file-system in the /uploads dir.

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting? @ABDELKADER BOUBEKEUR

Comment: I've got no error but the file is still not uploaded @OCeesay

Comment: Can you submit your entire route.js file? @ABDELKADER BOUBEKEUR

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have to place these html & js file into uploads folder in solution directory.check it out below code.

**Index.html Code:**

```
    <form id        =  "uploadForm"
         enctype   =  "multipart/form-data"
         action    =  "/api/photo"
         method    =  "post"
    >
    <input type="file" name="userPhoto" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" id="upload" name="submit">
    </form>
```

**Server.js Code:**

```
var express = require("express");
var multer = require('multer');

var app = express();

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        var splitted = file.originalname.split('.');
        var format = splitted[splitted.length - 1];
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + format);
    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('userPhoto');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post('/api/photo', function (req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.send("File is uploaded");
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```